# Error while trying to install GDAL using pip and easy_install with Python2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, gdal

My Error is

```
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I get this while trying to install GDAL using pip and easy_install with Python2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Please rewrite your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

sudo apt-get install python-gdal

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal
```

[Source](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-May/032946.html)