# How can I install GDAL in Ubuntu 16,04 with python 2.7.12 using pip?

Tags: python, pip, gdal

I am trying to import some specific libraries using python. it should be easy like importing numpy for example like so:

```
import osgeo.gdal, gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
```

But it seemed to me like the packages gdal and osgeo are missing so I went to the project interpreter to add these packages, Sadly i did not find the package osgeo and the package gdal could not be installed ... I looked it up in the net but it seems that there is no exact way to solve the matter.

I am using Ubuntu 16,04 with python **2.7.12** and **PS** GDAL is Geospatial Data Abstraction Library

This the error message that I am getting:

```
Collecting gdal
Using cached GDAL-2.2.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging347/gdal/setup.py", line 339, in <module>
    **extra )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 180, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 291, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 130, in add_defaults
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging347/gdal/setup.py", line 214, in finalize_options
    self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging347/gdal/setup.py", line 188, in get_gdal_config
    return fetch_config(option)
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging347/gdal/setup.py", line 141, in fetch_config
    raise gdal_config_error, e""")
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------

 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging347/gdal/
 You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? Did you installed the libraries using `apt-get` or `pip` or any other way? Did you install it for the proper python version?

Comment: Without error message nobody can tell what is wrong with your setup. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL is there and should be installable, given the dependencies are met.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Sorry for that I added the error log ... and I am using pip for installation of GDAL

Comment: Try these advices: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15004590/7976758

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution to my problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get -y install python-gdal
```

Thank you all for the contribution.